# getting excepected expression error

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

```
for (int i = [timeArray count] - 1; i >= 0; i–) {
        int timeComponent = [[timeArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
        switch (i) {
            case 3:
                hours = timeComponent;
                break;
            case 2:
                minutes = timeComponent;
                break;
            case 1:
                seconds = timeComponent;
                break;
            case 0:
                hundredths = timeComponent;
                hundredths++;
                break;

            default:
                break;
        }

    }
    if (hundredths == 100) {
        seconds++;
        hundredths = 0;
    }
    else if (seconds == 60) {
        minutes++;
        seconds = 0;
        minutes = 0;
    }
    self.hr.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.0d", hours];
    self.min.text = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%.2d", minutes];
    }
```

when i am excuting this code getting exception error at for loop  .how can i overcome this problem.please suggest me.
                         thankyou in advance

Comment: use i-- instead of i-

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Change your for loop as

```
for (int i = [timeArray count] - 1; i >= 0; i-–) {
        int timeComponent = [[timeArray objectAtIndex:i] intValue];
```

Answer (score 0):

You're not decrementing value of **i**(i-). And you wanna use decrement operator but (i-) this is not decrement operator. So please follow me

```
for (int i = [timeArray count] - 1; i >= 0; i–-) // ----- here your problem use i-- instead of i- 
{
}
```

Comment: In what way your answer is different from previous answer of Ramshad.

Comment: he didn't explain reason. So i've explained it.

Comment: Than you should put comment on that answer. A new answer should post only if the real answer is different. otherwise put comment or make edit to original answer.

Comment: You are right but at same time we are responsible to make SO clene. So take care that we don't make things duplicate thats why we don't allow duplicate question though it can create many point. We have many other question to answer. You can also get point by make edit to original answer. All the best.

Comment: thanks dear but i thought in this answer he's not clear so i gave the answer to make more clear. And i appreciate your thoughts...

Comment: yes I understand your thought and appreciate that. But I think making comment on original answer or give a edit is more better way. SO when some one read this question he don't get confused and get real answer very quickly. I can not force u to not put duplicate answer because there is no rules for it. I have just shared my view to make SO more useful and easy with you. It is not good place to discuss such thing so we should stop now.